# Can not change delimiters in vue.js 3.x

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

In vue.js 2.x I used to simply do

```
new Vue({
    delimiters: ['${', '}'],
    ...
}
```

But now it does not seem to work anymore in vue `3.0.2` or `3.1.2` :

```
 const app = Vue.createApp({
 delimiters: ['${', '}'],
     data() {
         return {
 
             display: 'redbox',
 
         }
     },
```

Follinwg the [docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-config.html#compileroptions-delimiters), I also tried adding it after constructor like:

```
 const app = Vue.createApp({...});
 app.compilerOptions.delimiters = ['${', '}'];
 app.mount("#vue-enhanced-page");
```

But it did not work either and the delimiters are shown literally like `${p.title}`. So appreciate your help to fix this.

It may worths noting that I import vue from cdn to my html page:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.1.2"></script>
```

Comment: You have `app.compilerOptions.delimiters` in your example, whereas the docs say `app.config.compilerOptions.delimiters`.

Comment: Right, thsi sovled the problem. My bad. Thank you!